# Datagrid binding (WPF) causing UI delay

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I want to be able to add items to a Data grid at a fast rate without causing UI delay.

Here is what I am doing now:
I am using an ObservableCollection that is bound to the data grid.

I use a background thread that loops and calls Invoke on the current dispatcher only when inserting/removing from the observable collection. Calling BeginInvoke instead has undesirable results.

I know that invoking that much on the dispatcher is causing the delay but I don't know what else to do.  I have used background workers before but I don't think that applies to my scenario.

What can I do to keep the UI responsive?

Comment: How many items does your collection contain, and how many items are you adding?  Is there any other code which follows on from the insertion (such as CollectionChanged handling, or code that runs when an item is bound)?

Comment: The collection starts out with 0 items and adds one at a time.  If there are more than 10 one will be removed.  The UI will lag when i am adding around 100 items a second.  No extra code follows the insertion other than removing if there are more than 10 items in the collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Batch the updates -- the background thread could add items to a queue and you can periodically refresh your bound observable collection by invocation. Take a look at the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace if you need to handle multi-threaded producers

Comment: System.Collections.Concurrent is only available in .NET 4 FWIW

Answer (score 6):

A major weakness in your design is that by binding to an ObservableCollection, you are causing the UI to render every item that get's added to the list (possibly thousands) - even if at the end of processing there are only 10 items which need to be rendered.

I saw huge improvements by changing the ObservableCollection to a List, and refreshing the DataGrid manually at the end of processing - this way the UI only ever needs to process 10 items.  I found that this change caused a 50% performance gain, as well as allowing the UI to be 100% responsive while the List is being processed.

If you are processing the list for a long time, and need to show live changes, you could refresh the DataGrid every 100 items.  This would show results with about 0.5 second accuracy which should be close enough.