# How can I speed up ListBox rendering and ListCollectionView filtering?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, optimization, filtering

A two-pronged question here, but I think these two subjects are entwined enough to warrant their inclusion together.

In our application, we have a `ListBox`, which is populated with what might be a large number of items. Each of these items is displayed with a rather complicated item template. It's necessarily rather complicated, and while it could potentially be pared down a little more I probably couldn't take a huge amount out. The items in the `ListBox` come from a `ListCollectionView` which is constructed from an `ObservableCollection<>` of the objects to display.

We have two problems.

The first is that when we reconfigure filters for the `ListCollectionView` and call `Refresh` on it, there is a very noticable lock-up of a few seconds in the UI while it's torn down and recreated, and the `ListBox` repopulates. The duration of this lock-up seems to be related to the number of elements contained in the `ListBox`, and is longest when the `ListBox`'s client area is full of items. We're pretty certain that the lock-up is caused by the item templates being recreated. I have tried turning on virtualization, but this had no effect in reducing or eliminating the slowdown. I'm also looking at some other optimizations, like examining our bindings and modifying the layouts. Is there any method for either avoiding this particular issue, speeding it up, or moving it to a different thread? (I know the last one's highly unlikely because the rendering is all single-threaded, but perhaps there's some workaround...)

The second relates to the filtering on the `ListCollectionView`. While it isn't an issue at present, we think that there's potential for the filtering to become an issue and cause a noticeable lock-up on the UI thread. I am working to reduce the filtering overhead, but I was wondering if there's a method for moving the Refresh call on the `ListCollectionView` on to a different thread? None of my attempts thus far have succeeded, seemingly because the `ListCollectionView` doesn't automatically marshal certain events on to the correct thread.

Pointers to or explanations of any known or potential solutions to these two issues would be very helpful.

Comment: I have the same problem with my wpf project. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: It's been a while :) I seem to remember that we really aggressively optimized the template, and refactored the filtering to move the majority of it on to a different thread. That made the lock-up much less noticeable. Unfortunately, I've changed jobs since, so I don't know if any further work was done. It may be that they've switched to a third-party `ListBox`-like control that performs better - we did that for our grids.

Answer (score 2):

Some interesting ideas in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174678/datagrid-binding-wpf-causing-ui-delay) SO thread about datagrid rendering and binding - you may be able to apply them to your listbox scenario as well...

Comment: I think this might be a potential solution if we were adding or removing items. When applying a Filter though, it seems that the ListBox must be repopulated. If it is unavoidable, then so is the stall that accompanies it, which is mildly annoying. A symptom of WPF's single-threaded rendering. Hopefully, there will be some remedy for it in the future. For the time being, I guess I'll have to try to optimize our DataTemplate some more. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can virtualize AND filter at the same time. So, if I were in your shoes, I'd stick with a virtualizing list box and do the filtering logic in another thread. Sure, you might have to write some code that's already been written before, but if it doesn't lock up your GUI? Worth it.

Answer (score 1):

2 tips from [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/10PerformanceTips.html), the first one might help for virtualizing the `ListBox`:

Virtualize lists and views by using a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as `ItemsPanel` for lists. This only creates the visible elements at load time. All other elements are lazy created when they get visible. Be aware that grouping or `CanContentScroll="True"` prevents virtualization!

Enable Container Recycling. Virtualization brings a lot of performance improvements, but the containers will be disposed and re created, this is the default. But you can gain more performance by recycle containers by setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`

I did virtualization of my huge list of objects by the technique described [here on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataVirtualization.aspx), it works nicely

Comment: That's an interesting article. It might be useful when we're reading in the objects that appear in the ListBox; I'll take a look at implementing it.

Regarding the VirtualizingStackPanel: I have it set up, but unfortunately, it hasn't addressed the ListBox stall. Thanks, though.

Comment: The original poster has a valid question involving ListCollectionView and has already turned on virtualization.  I am running into this same problem: the Refresh appears to recreate the items.  I've already confirmed that virtualization is working by scrolling, but when I filter or sort using the view, WPF recreated all the items in the ListView.